# How to find the anagrams from a text file

Tags: python-3.x

all anagrams from a given text file. I tried but code is not working. no output at  all.

```
 def anagrams( s1, s2 ):
    s1_list = list(s1.lower())
    s1_list.sort()
    s2_list = list(s2.lower())
    s2_list.sort()

    if s1.lower() == s2.lower():
        return(False)
    elif s1_list == s2_list:
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False) 
        def find_all_anagrams( string ):
            anagrams_list = []
            with open("English.txt", "r") as fileObject:
                for line in fileObject: 
                    word = line.strip()
            if anagrams(string, word):
                anagrams_list.append(word)
                return anagrams_list
```

Output should print all the anagrams from text file

Comment: Please do _not_ post code as images. Paste it as text.

Comment: [images of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) are not helpful. please copy-paste your code directly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The indentations in your code is all  messed up. I tried correcting it as below.

```
def anagrams( s1, s2 ):
    #convert the strings to lower case and sort them
    s1 = sorted(s1.lower())
    s2 = sorted(s2.lower())
    #If the string match, they are anagrams else they are not
    return s1 == s2

def find_all_anagrams( string ):
    anagrams_list = []
    with open("english.txt", "r") as fileObject:
        #Match each word in file against the string, and if it an anagram
        #append it to anagram list
        for line in fileObject:
            word = line.strip()
            if anagrams(string, word):
                anagrams_list.append(word)
    return anagrams_list

print(find_all_anagrams('abcd'))
```

Example if the input file is as below and string is `abcd`

```
abcd
bcda
aaaa
bbbb
abdc
xxxx
x
y
z
aaabcd
```

The output will be

```
['abcd', 'bcda', 'abdc']
```

Comment: one more question: output ['abcd', 'bcda', 'abdc'] for print(find_all_anagrams('abcd')).

Comment: Isn't that the expected output?

Comment: yes. i need to give input here so that i can get output